# Nitrous.IO Chromebook cloud based IDE

Tags: arduino, nitrousio, chromebook

Hi I have a quick question about nitrous.IO. I was wondering if it could be used to compile code for an arduino?

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous.IO permit to install or run many things, like web server with php and mysql or Google App Engine or Java application and Python. So I'm pretty sure you can install the tool-chain avr-gcc, avr-libc and other stuff needed on you user space.

Just for information **make** and **gcc** are available in standard via the shell command panel in your Nitrous box.

You can read [this tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-unix.html) to understand the way to compile all tools need to perform a compilation for arduino in Linux environment.

I not tested that but I'm pretty sure is possible.